# Button and hover effect not working in react js project

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css, buttonclick

Buttons and hover effect is not working in laptop screen when I go to mobile responsive all buttons and hover effect work properly and also hyperlink not working
Please help ?

```
<div className='md:pl-0 pl-[20px]'>
                    <button
                    onClick={navigate('/contactus')}
                        className='w-[218px] h-[56px] relative inline-flex   bg-[#FE6910] hover:bg-[#FE6910]/80 duration-300 justify-evenly items-center md:mt-[56px] mt-[20px]'>
                        <div
                            className="absolute transitiona-all duration-1000 opacity-70 -inset-px bg-gradient-to-r from-[#FE6910] via-[#FE6910] to-[#FE6910]/70 rounded-xl blur-lg group-hover:opacity-100 group-hover:-inset-1 group-hover:duration-200 animate-tilt">
                        </div>
                        <div className=' gap-[30px] relative inline-flex items-center justify-center    font-bold text-white transition-all duration-200    focus:outline-none focus:ring-2 focus:ring-offset-2 focus:ring-gray-900'>
                            <p className='text-[17px] font-roboto font-medium text-white '>Contact Us</p>
                            <BsArrowRight size={30} className='text-white ' />

                        </div>
                    </button>
- -                 </div>
```

Comment: Can you provide more context? What's those class names you're applying and where do they come from?

Comment: @Hiimdjango those class names are from [Tailwind CSS](https://tailwindcss.com/).

Answer (score 0):

How're you doing?
Since you haven't posted details of your classnames, I cannot help with your hover effect problem. But, with your navigation, you should provide a callback function to `onClick` property of your button. I mean, something like this:

```js
<button onClick={() => navigate('/contactus')}>
  [ELEMENTS INSIDE BUTTON]
</button>
```

You can also use the `Link` element of react-router-dom like this:

```js
<Link to="/contactus">
  <button>
    [ELEMENTS INSIDE BUTTON]
  </button>
</Link>
```

Second alternative is a better approach since it wraps an `a` element and browsers and screen readers can verify that it's a link.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Also Simple buttons is not working in laptop and any other big screen

Comment: Just try to remove class names and check whether it works, We can check if the problem is with those CSS classes or something else.